# Regedit GUI Connect Network Registry by command line

Tags: powershell, cmd, regedit

I would like to be able to launch the regedit GUI by automatically connecting to a given computer with a command line for having something like here:

[GUI when connected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAf1j.png)

Unfortunately I can't find any topic talking about it except for doing it by hand: File > Connect Network

Comment: I couldn't find official documentation for `regedit.exe`'s command-line options, but [this](https://ss64.com/nt/regedit.html) suggests that connecting to a given computer from the command line isn't supported.

Comment: `regedit.exe` also requires to be run elevated, so you'd need to have remote Administrative access just to open it.